# Capturing emails with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I will be gathering scattered emails from a larger CSV file. I am just now learning regex. I am trying to extract the emails from this example sentence. However, emails is populating with only the @ symbol and the letter immediately before that. Can you help me see what's going wrong?

```
import re

String = "'Jessica's email is jessica@gmail.com, and Daniel's email is daniel123@gmail.com. Edward's is edwardfountain@gmail.com, and his grandfather, Oscar's, is odawg@gmail.com.'"

emails = re.findall(r'.[@]', String)
names = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*',String)

print(emails)
print(names)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your regex e-mail is not working at all: `emails = re.findall(r'.[@]', String)` matches anychar then `@`.

I would try a different approach: match the sentences and extract name,e-mails couples with the following empiric assumptions (if your text changes too much, that would break the logic)

- all names are followed by `'s"` and `is` somewhere (using non-greedy `.*?` to match all that is in between
- `\w` matches any alphanum char (or underscore), and only one dot for domain (else it matches the final dot of the sentence)

code:

```
import re

String = "'Jessica's email is jessica@gmail.com, and Daniel's email is daniel123@gmail.com. Edward's is edwardfountain@gmail.com, and his grandfather, Oscar's, is odawg@gmail.com.'"

print(re.findall("(\w+)'s.*? is (\w+@\w+\.\w+)",String))
```

result:

```
[('Jessica', 'jessica@gmail.com'), ('Daniel', 'daniel123@gmail.com'), ('Edward', 'edwardfountain@gmail.com'), ('Oscar', 'odawg@gmail.com')]
```

converting to `dict` would even give you a dictionary name => address:

```
{'Oscar': 'odawg@gmail.com', 'Jessica': 'jessica@gmail.com', 'Daniel': 'daniel123@gmail.com', 'Edward': 'edwardfountain@gmail.com'}
```

The general case needs more chars (not sure I'm exhaustive):

```
String = "'Jessica's email is jessica_123@gmail.com, and Daniel's email is daniel-123@gmail.com. Edward's is edward.fountain@gmail.com, and his grandfather, Oscar's, is odawg@gmail.com.'"

print(re.findall("(\w+)'s.*? is ([\w\-.]+@[\w\-.]+\.[\w\-]+)",String))
```

result:

```
[('Jessica', 'jessica_123@gmail.com'), ('Daniel', 'daniel-123@gmail.com'), ('Edward', 'edward.fountain@gmail.com'), ('Oscar', 'odawg@gmail.com')]
```

Answer (score 2):

**1.** **Emails**

```
    In [1382]: re.findall(r'\S+@\w+\.\w+', text)
    Out[1382]: 
    ['jessica@gmail.com',
     'daniel123@gmail.com',
     'edwardfountain@gmail.com',
     'odawg@gmail.com']
```

How it works: All emails are `xxx@xxx.xxx`. One thing to note is a bunch of characters surrounding `@`, and the singular `.`.  So, we use `\S` to demarcate anything that is not a whitespace. And `+` is to search for 1 or more such characters. `\w+\.\w+` is just a fancy way of saying search for a string that only has one `.` in it.

---

**2.** **Names**

```
    In [1375]: re.findall('[A-Z][\S]+(?=\')', text)
    Out[1375]: ['Jessica', 'Daniel', 'Edward', 'Oscar']
```

How it works: Any word starting with an upper case. The `(?=\')` is a lookahead. As you see, all names follow the pattern `Name's`. We want everything before the apostrophe. Hence, the lookahead, which is not captured.

---

Now, if you want to map names to emails by capturing them together with one massive regex, you can. [*Jean-François Fabre's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45498584/4909087) is a good start. But I recommend getting the basics down par first.

Comment: `odawg@gmail.com.`: last e-mail has a dot in the end, others get the commas as well :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre [Last 24 hours](https://puu.sh/x1aUC/32ef6e3aea.png). Yeah it's been a tough day -- tough crowd to please.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Honestly I start exercising my hammer when I need to blow off some steam -- which has been happening quite often actually.

Comment: 470 and you're complaining? I admit a lot of users don't accept answers (or accept the lamest/least upvoted answer there is because they understand it)

Comment: I just realised that `[\w_]` is redundant since `\w` contains `_` !

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre random much? ;) but you're right, I guess I can edit when I'm at a PC.

Comment: doesn't hurt. Now I realize that we should have closed as a duplicate of "how to extract emails from string", but I felt I had to explain OP _why_ his attempt doesn't work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre For some reason, I did close it... and I reopened it again... not sure why though :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to find anchors, patterns to match. An improved pattern could be:

```
import re

String = "'Jessica's email is jessica@gmail.com, and Daniel's email is 
daniel123@gmail.com. Edward's is edwardfountain@gmail.com, and his 
grandfather, Oscar's, is odawg@gmail.com.'"

emails = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+', String)
names = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*', String)

print(emails) 
print(names)
```

\w+ is missing '-' which are allowed in email adresses.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not using the repeat operator. The below code uses the + operator which means the characters / sub patterns just before it can repeat 1 to many times.

```
s = '''Jessica's email is jessica@gmail.com, and Daniel's email is daniel123@gmail.com. Edward's is edwardfountain@gmail.com, and his grandfather, Oscar's, is odawg@gmail.com.'''

p = r'[a-z0-9]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+'
ans = re.findall(p, s)

print(ans)
```

Comment: Thanks m8. Like I said I am new to this regex.